# Excel VBA Selection.Copy no longer works

Tags: excel, selection, vba

I'm getting a "Compile error: Expected Function or variable" from this code

```
Cells(3, 2).Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = Formula 'Inserts formula
'Copies formula across the row
Cells(3, 2).Copy
Range(Cells(3, 2), Cells(3, 10)).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulas 
Range(Cells(3, 2), Cells(3, 10)).Select
'Copies the formula down to end of list
selection.Copy '<---- Here it says it can't compile
Range(selection, selection.End(xlDown)).FillDown
```

Using "selection" here gives the error, yet works in another workbook. I'm trying to insert a formula into a cell, copy it across a range, and fill down to the end of the block of data. How do I either get it to work again? Or, is there another way to populate a range of cells with a formula (which changes often hence putting it in a variable.)

Thank you for your help,
Samuel Smith

Comment: Did you accidentally define a variable called `selection` ? That may be why 'selection' isn't capitalized in your code.

Comment: On an optimization note, it's best that you do not select cells. Since you know the cell address might as well set it to a range and use the `offset`, `value` for processing. It makes things much faster.

Comment: Try substituting your code with   Range(Cells(3, 2), Cells(3, 10).End(xlDown)).Formula = Formula

Comment: @TimWilliams You guessed right. I wrote a short subroutine named "selection" and that broke my Selection references. Thank you!

Comment: @bonCodigo and nightcrawler23, thank you for your suggestions. The formula has cell references which change with position, done automatically by Excel when you copy formulas. I'm still learning how to address ranges directly with referenced formulas.