# excel vba copy-paste data in different workbooks

Tags: vba, excel

my code is

```
 t = wb.Sheets("Central_Scheme").UsedRange.Rows.Count
 wb.Sheets("Central_Scheme").Range("A1:L" & t).Select
 Selection.Copy
 Workbooks("Central.xlsm").Activate
 Sheets("Sheet3").Range("A1:L" & t).Paste
```

I am getting an error "**Object doesnt support this property/method**". Please help me to correct the code

Comment: Which object throw the error?

Comment: Selection.Copy is throwing an error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would avoiding the selection copy paste route by using the method outlined here http://www.excelitems.com/2010/12/optimize-vba-code-for-faster-macros.html
work? Go down to "avoid unnecessary copy / paste".

Comment: Not sure... But have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13635768/excel-vba-selection-copy-no-longer-works